# Correct application of Laplace's Rule of Succession to actual effectiveness in Student Problem Sets?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, binomial-distribution

I recently came across [3blue1brown's YouTube short](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/qBZKJNWFoH4) on **Laplace's Rule of Succession**, as well as his [two videos on the probability of probabilities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8idr1WZ1A7Q). In these videos, he uses the example of Amazon reviews to explain how Laplace's Rule of Succession can provide a better estimate of the likelihood of having a positive experience with a specific seller. The rule suggests adding one positive and one negative review to the available data and then calculating the overall rating.

I'm interested to know *whether Laplace's Rule of Succession can also be applied to evaluate a student's performance in solving problem sets*. Specifically, I'm curious if adding one positive and one negative data point to the existing sample could provide insights into their effective performance. Currently, I am preparing for a board examination similar to the PE Engineering Exam, and I believe tracking my performance using this rule might be helpful.

I'm wondering if the underlying assumption of Laplace's Rule of Succession, which assumes a *constant* true probability for an event (such as an Amazon seller's rating), still holds true when analyzing a student's historical performance data in solving problem sets (e.g., 21/25, 43/50, 72/75, etc.). While the true probability of a student's performance may change over time as they improve their understanding of a subject, the original assumption remains valid for a specific point in time. I believe this motivation could also apply to general student grades, and I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: When preparing for an exam, we would expect practice exams to be of equal difficulty and thus for scores to improve over time. So we'd need a model for this improvement. On the other hand, in the usual setting of problem sets, the student's ability improves over time, but the difficulty of the problem sets also increases over time. This makes the trend in scores hard to predict, but perhaps a constant probability is an effective if crude model.

Comment: I see there might be too many moving factors at play. Perhaps Laplace's rule of succession (aside from the usual methods for time series analyses) is not that good of a fit or might be unnecessary to get an idea on a student's probability to pass a "final" exam?

What you pointed out on equal difficulty for practice exams, for my current use case that would be more accurate than progressively harder problem sets. To simplify, I am assuming that problems of varying difficulty are randomly sampled from a constant set so that over time the difficulty is averaged. Thank you for your thoughts.